# How to set offset committed by the consumer group using Spark's Direct Stream for Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to use [Spark's Direct Approach (No Receivers) for Kafka](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers), I have following Kafka configuration map:

```
configMap.put("zookeeper.connect","192.168.51.98:2181");
configMap.put("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
configMap.put("auto.offset.reset","smallest");
configMap.put("auto.commit.enable","true");
configMap.put("topics","IPDR31");
configMap.put("kafka.consumer.id","kafkasparkuser");
configMap.put("bootstrap.servers","192.168.50.124:9092");
```

Now my objective is, if my Spark pipeline crashes and it is started again, the stream should be started from the latest offset committed by the consumer group. So, for that purpose, I want to specify the starting offset for consumer. I have information about the offsets committed in each partition. How I can supply this information to the streaming function. Currently I am using

```
JavaPairInputDStream<byte[], byte[]> kafkaData =
   KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(js, byte[].class, byte[].class,
     DefaultDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class,configMap,topic);
```

Comment: How to get the information  about the offsets committed in each partition? Can you please explain that.

Comment: you can get this information from zookeeper. you can refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka) to figure out the code in java

Comment: But, using directstream is it not possible without updating zookeeper? Can check-pointing achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the second form of createDirectStream in the [Spark API docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$) - it allows you to pass in a `Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>`, where the Long is the offset.

Note that Spark will not automatically update your offsets in Zookeeper when using a DirectInputStream - you have to write them yourself either to ZK or some other database. Unless you have a strict requirement of exactly-once semantics, it will be easier to use the createStream method to get back a DStream, in which case Spark will update the offsets in ZK and resume from the last stored offset in the case of failure.

Comment: Does the stream commit some offset to kafka itself so that when application restarts it starts from that offset. Is it entirely upto the application to manage the offset.

Comment: Kafka doesn't store client offsets. If you use the standard createStream method, Spark will take care of updating offsets in zookeeper and restart from the correct offset in the case of failure (though do note this has at least once semantics). If you use the createDirectStream method, you have to manage the offsets yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, the correct solution is to use checkpoint. For every RDDStream processed, checkpoint will write the metadata to a shared storage specified (typically hdfs). Its metadata, not the real data so there is no real performance impact.

If the spark process is crashed and restarted, it will first read the checkpoint and resume from the saved offsets from checkpoint.

You can refer the sample code where i use spark streaming to write data to elasticsearch reliabily using checkpoint. 
https://github.com/atulsm/Test_Projects/blob/master/src/spark/StreamingKafkaRecoverableDirectEvent.java

Comment: yes i came across the check-pointing method earlier but then what's the difference in using zookeeper as the coordinator and hdfs as metastore? which can be the better solution and why?

Comment: With zookeeper, you have to implement your own logic, so its an adhoc solution. Checkpoint is supported out of the box and spark have inbuilt methods to do that.

Comment: I am trying the check-pointing feature. What I need is whenever the application restarts, it should start from the last accessed offsets for each Kafka partition from the last run. But, it doesn't seem to happen. Any comments?

Comment: @AswinJoseRoy this is what the checkpoint is used for. If its not working make sure you are using JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate() metod and using a shared folder like hdfs. Check the sample program in the github link pasted above.

Comment: @AtulSoman I used checkpoint, however it appears that it cash not only offsets, but also stream settings, eg interval and window size... Is it I'm doing something wrong or it's expected behaviour? Thank you in advance

Comment: @KonstantinKudryavtsev This is expected. Metadata stored in checkpoint also contains the configuration settings used to create the streaming application.

Comment: @AtulSoman thank you, that's what I thought... any idea how to overcome it? I need a possibility to restart stream with a new window/sliding, but continue working from the latest processed data

Comment: @KonstantinKudryavtsev. I am not sure. I guess you might have to try the non-checkpoint approach of using createDirectStream with Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>. Similar to the approach provided in the accepted answer.